# How to make elements(dynamic) obtained as JSON response, clickable in Android and connecting them to some web link?

Tags: android, json, eclipse, android-layout, layout-inflater

The following is the CODE I am using to get the data from Codeforces.com API as JSON response. If anyone can please help me improve this to convert them to clickable links and then attach a web link to them.  :

```
public class Http extends Activity {

TextView httpStuff;
HttpClient client;
JSONObject json;
final static String URL = "http://codeforces.com/api/user.status?handle=";
String m = "";
public static String[] sarr = new String[200];
public static String[] name = new String[200];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.httpex);

    httpStuff = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHttp);
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    new Read().execute("result");
}

public JSONObject lastSub(String username) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
    url.append(username);
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());

    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if(status == 200) {
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        JSONObject last = new JSONObject(data);
        //JSONObject last = new JSONObject(data).getJSONArray("result").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("problem");
        JSONArray array = new JSONObject(data).getJSONArray("result");
        String m1=null, m2=null, m3=null;
        String n1 = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        int cnt=0, flag=0;
        for(int k=0; k<array.length(); k++)
        {
            last = array.getJSONObject(k).getJSONObject("problem");
            JSONObject v = array.getJSONObject(k);
            if(v.getString("verdict").contentEquals("OK")) {
                m1 = last.getString("name");
                m2= last.getString("contestId");
                m2= m2.concat("/");
                m3= last.getString("index");
                m2 = m2.concat(m3);
                flag = 0;
                for(int i=0; i<cnt; i++) {
                    if (sarr[i].equals(m1)) {
                        flag = 1;
                    }
                }
                    if(flag == 0) {
                        m = m.concat(m1);
                        m= m.concat(n1);
                        sarr[cnt] = m1;
                        name[cnt] = m2;
                        cnt++;
                    }
            }
        }
        return last;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(Http.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return null;

    }
}

public class Read extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            json = lastSub("avm12&from=1&count=100");
            return m;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          httpStuff.setText(result);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: You can use a listview and define its onClick? The link field from JSON should be invoked on this.

Comment: @Skynet can u send me a link from where i can learn to implement that

Comment: Look at the section `Listener`. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: The question is too broad, however [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) should give you a fair idea.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your main layout `R.layout.httpex` has a `ListView`.

(Should look like this)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Create a new layout `list_item.xml` representing the data you want to display :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pTitle"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pUrl"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then edit your code like this :

```
public class Http extends Activity {

TextView httpStuff;
HttpClient client;
JSONObject json;
final static String URL = "http://codeforces.com/api/user.status?handle=";
String m = "";
ListView list;
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> problemdata= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
//above ArrayList replacing sarr & name

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.httpex);
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

httpStuff = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHttp);
client = new DefaultHttpClient();
new Read().execute("result");
}

public JSONObject lastSub(String username) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
    url.append(username);
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());

    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (status == 200) {
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        JSONObject last = new JSONObject(data);
        //JSONObject last = new JSONObject(data).getJSONArray("result").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("problem");
        JSONArray array = new JSONObject(data).getJSONArray("result");
        String n1 = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        for (int k = 0; k < array.length(); k++) {
            last = array.getJSONObject(k).getJSONObject("problem");
            JSONObject v = array.getJSONObject(k);
            if (v.getString("verdict").contentEquals("OK")) {

                HashMap<String, String> d = new HashMap<String, String>();
                d.put("NAME",last.getString("name"));
                d.put("URL","http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/"+last.getString("contestId")+"/"+last.getString("index"));
                if(!problemdata.contains(d)) {
                    m = m.concat(last.getString("name")).concat(n1); //m+=last.getString("name")+"\r\n";
                    problemdata.add(d);
                }
            }
        }
        return last;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(Http.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return null;

    }
}

public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            json = lastSub("avm12&from=1&count=100");
            return m;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        httpStuff.setText(result);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                 //get the url from the invisible TextView ad opens it on the default browser
                 TextView t=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pUrl);
                 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(t.getText().toString())));
            }
        });
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Http.this, problemdata,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "NAME", "URL" }, new int[] { R.id.pTitle,
                R.id.pUrl});
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
}
```